# AMDGPU-PRO How to associate GPU stats found in /sys/kernel/debug/dri and /sys/class/drm/?

Tags: gpu

I'm trying to monitor AMD gpus in a system running AMDGPU-PRO 18.10 and linux kernel 4.4.0.

I am reading values from:

`/sys/kernel/debug/dri/$X/amdgpu_pm_info`

where $X is a card index.

I am also reading the pp_dpm_cclk values from another directory, found under

`/sys/class/drm/card$X/`

I have 2 questions about this.

Does $X in both these cases refer to the same card? E.g. is `/sys/class/drm/card0/device/pp_dpm_mclk` returning information about the same card as `/sys/kernel/debug/dri/0/amdgpu_pm_info`?

Will this be true every boot/if I add or remove cards?

Finally, should I be using `/sys/devices/pci0000:00` to access pp_dpm_mclk rather than the symlinks in `/sys/class/drm`? If so, how can I find out which card in `/sys/devices/pci0000:00` corresponds to the cards in `/sys/kernel/debug/dri` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First question the answer is Yes.
`/sys/kernel/debug/dri/0` is for card `/sys/class/drm/card0` and so on..

> Will this be true every boot/if I add or remove cards?

Considering my personal case:
I have 3 pcie x16 on my motherboard. This is order as they are physicaly on my board.

```
  PCIEx16 [================] bus 0000:65:00.0 First slot
  PCIEx16 [================] bus 0000:17:00.0 Second slot
  PCIEx16 [================] bus 0000:15:00.0 Third slot
```

If you have one video cards plug into bus `65`. Bus `65` will be card0.
But if you add a second video card into bus `17`, this will reorder all the card in  `/sys/class/drm/card$X`.

card0 will be bus `17`, and `card1` bus `65`.
Same with one more card on bus 15.
card0 bus `15`, card1 bus `17`, card2 bus `65`.

So the card number is depending of the pcie slot you have plug in the video card and the number of video cards you currently have installed on your motherboard.

> Finally, should I be using `/sys/devices/pci0000:00` to access
>   pp_dpm_mclk rather than the symlinks in `/sys/class/drm`? If so, how can
>   I find out which card in `/sys/devices/pci0000:00` corresponds to the
>   cards in `/sys/kernel/debug/dri` ?

When you `cd` into `/sys/class/drm/card0/device` this is a symlink to `/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:$PCI.0/subsystem/devices/0000:$PCI:00.0`

Both are the same.